# Crear google chart a partir de información de base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, chart.js

Quiero que se genere el chart de google a partir de los datos que se guardan en los textarea tras la consulta sql.
En el chart de columnas quiero que cambie de color en función de si supera un porcentaje, es decir, el valor de los text/50 si el porcentaje es mayor al 50% la barra será de color rojo y si no de color azul.

Otra cuestión para poner la gráfica que salga en el lado derecho de la pantalla en paralelo a los textarea, sin usar css ,¿como se haría?.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
<div id="chart_div"></div>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
  
          google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

function drawAxisTickColors() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Nivel de Demanda Diario');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad de Personas');
      

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8:00'}, parseInt($('body').find('#1ºhora').attr('value'));],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10:00'},  parseInt($('body').find('#2ºhora').attr('value'));]],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Nivel de Demanda Diario',
        focusTarget: 'category',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Horario',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          },
          
         
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Porcentaje de Demanda',
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
            color: '#67001f',
            bold: false,
            italic: false
          
          
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<?php
$consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total from tfg.reservas WHERE  fecha='2019-05-29'and  hora  < '10:00:00' AND hora > '08:00:00';";

                            if ($resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta )) {

    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                            }
?>
<div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 8:00 a 10:00</span></a>
                            <text class="badge badge-dark" name="1ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="1ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
                                <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
                                </div>
                                
                               <?php

 $consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total from tfg.reservas WHERE  fecha='2019-05-29'and  hora  < '12:00:00' AND hora > '10:00:00';";

                            if ($resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta )) {

    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                            }
            
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 10:00 a 12:00</span></a>
                            <text class="badge badge-dark" name="2ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="2ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
                                <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
                                </div>
          </div>
```